# Knockout add to array of an array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am looking for a way to add an item to an array that belongs to an item within another array using knockout and knockout mapping.

I have the following, a Person which has an array of WorkItems that has an array of ActionPlans. Person > WorkItems > ActionPlans

Knockout code is as follows -

```
var PersonViewModel = function(data) {
var self = this;
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, trainingCourseItemMapping, self);

self.addWorkItem = function() {
    var WorkItem = new WorkItemVM({
        Id: null,
        JobSkillsAndExpDdl: "",
        JobSkillsAndExperience: "",
        ActionPlans: ko.observableArray(),
        PersonId: data.Id
        })
   self.WorkItems.push(WorkItem)
};

self.addActionPlan = function () {
    var actionPlan = new ActionPlanVM({
        Id: null,
        priorityAreaStage: "",
        goal: "",
        action: "",
        byWho: "",
        byWhen: ""
        WorkItemId: data.Id
    });
    self.ActionPlans.push(actionPlan);
};
}
```

Array mapping

```
var trainingCourseItemMapping = {
'WorkItem': {
    key: function(workitem) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(workitem.Id);
    },
    create: function(options) {
        return new WorkItemVM(options.data);
    },
    'ActionPlans': {
        key: function (actionPlanItem) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(actionPlanItem.id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new ActionPlanVM(options.data);
        }

    }
}
```

Array item mapping

```
var WorkItemVM = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, trainingCourseItemMapping, self);
}

var ActionPlanVM = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

And within my view i want to have the following (edited) -

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkItems">
//body table html here
</tbody>

<!--ko foreach: WorkItems-->
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ActionPlans">
//body table html here
</tbody>
<!--/ko-->
```

**Error**

The error i am currently getting is -

Unable to process binding "click: function(){return addActionPlan }"

How can i push an item to the "nested" action plan array of WorkItems? Thanks

Edit -

Image as requested -

[image]

Preceding this is a "add work item" button within the main Form. When Save is pressed the WorkItem is shown within a table row (all working fine)

Comment: Please do add the image, I'm interested in this question but not sure how to help.

Comment: Image added thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that you have ActionPlans WITHIN WorkItems, so your binds should reflect that too:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkItems">
//body table html here
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ActionPlans"> /*ActionPlans exists in this context*/
    //body table html here
    </tbody>
</tbody>
```

with your current HTML ActionPlans are not defined in their binding context
This is where the specific error comes from, ActionPlans are not defined in a "sibling" context, they are properties of each WorkItem

EDIT:
You might also try virtual elements, knockout's containerless syntax, allthough this is not advised in general ( bad performance relative to the rest of the framework, some problems may occur with minifier's removing comments etc)

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkItems">
    //body table html here

    </tbody>

<!-- ko foreach: WorkItems -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ActionPlans"> 
    </tbody>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You best option thought is to restruct your VM!

EDIT 2:
Try this in your personVM

```
self.addActionPlanToWorkItem = function (workItem) {
    var actionPlan = new ActionPlanVM({
        Id: null,
        priorityAreaStage: "",
        goal: "",
        action: "",
        byWho: "",
        byWhen: ""
        WorkItemId: workItem.Id
   });
    workItem.ActionPlans.push(actionPlan);
};
```

Call it from anywhere and pass in your current active WorkItem, it will add a new empty ActionPlan to your model.

Or you can maybe try out this way:
Replace workItemVM with this

```
    var WorkItemVM = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, trainingCourseItemMapping, self);
        self.addActionPlan = function(actionPlanToAdd) 
        {
            self.ActionPlans.push(actionPlanToAdd);
         };
    }
```

and call it on your workItems as

```
someWorkItemInstance.addActionPlan(new ActionPPlanVM())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however...i cant seem to implement that type of binding due to ActionPlans being with a bootstrap modal. Is there syntax that can reflect this within the foreach: binding such as "foreach: WorkItems.ActionPlans"?

Comment: You could do it probably using knockouts containerless syntax a.k.a virtual elements. I will edit the answer in a min with an example

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply on this one (ive been on another project) unfortunately i am not having any luck with the virtual elements...you mention restructuring my VM any thoughts on the best way to do this? thanks

Comment: How do you want to display them exactly? i mean you have a list of WorkItems on each person, and each WorkItem has a list of ActionPlans.How do you want to represent them in the ui? With your current html it is as if you are trying to render 2 tables, so say you have 3 workitems, each with 2 action plans you want 1 table only with the items and a compeltely seperate table only with all the action plans? Are you sure you are not trying to have html where the first tables entry have a corellation with the 2nd one? Draw me something using 2x3 relation and upload an img :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically Person is a form where you can add work items. Clicking the add work item button opens a bootstrap modal. Here you can fill a Work Item form - works perfectly. The bit that does not is where you can dynamically add/remove rows to a table of ActionPlans hence the collection..il knock up an image if you still need one...

Comment: Edited my question...not sure if you have anymore ideas

Comment: As you are right now you have to change your WorkItemVM.
WorkItemVM should contain your 'addActionPlan ' method.
In your current addActionPlan , your self is pointing to something without any ActionPlan obsArray. So you WorkItem vm should contain this function, since adding a new ActionPlan means to push a new ActionPlan to one of your WorkItems

Comment: 'self.ActionPlans.push(actionPlan);' This is the problem, since there is no ActionPlans in that 'self' context... You sould be doing WorkItems()[0].ActionPlans.push() for example.

Comment: Cheers...using self.WorkItems()[0].ActionPlans.push(actionPlan); doesnt work, however this does -  'self.WorkItems._latestValue[0].ActionPlans.push(actionPlan); Two issues i have here is that the foreach: ActionPlans now shows all ActionPlans instead of just the "parent" ActionPlan and I also need to work out how i can add to other WorkItems in the array ie not just [0]

Comment: Edited the answer once more, hope it helps a bit further

Comment: Excellent thanks you have cetianly helped this issue along. However for the foreach statment i had to use - <tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkItemEdit() && WorkStarItem().ActionPlans"> to loop through the ActionPlans. All appears to be working now...and moving the actionplans push function to the WorkItemVM has also worked.